# Ruby on Rails validation bypass and confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I am facing a strange thing on Ruby on Rails and I don't know what is the correct way to deal with this situation.

I have two models, Book and Page.

**Book(name:string)**

**Page(page_number: integer, book_id: ID)**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  validates_uniqueness_of :page_number, scope: :book_id
end
```

I have created a view from where I can update a book. I accept nested attributes for pages and there is a section where I can update book pages as well as add new pages (by a Javascript function that lets the user to add a new page row by clicking + button). As you can see I have a validation that requires the page number to be unique for a certain book to prevent duplication. I have also defined an unique index on the database level (using Postgres)

On my update action in Book's Controller I have:

```
def update
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
    flash[:notice] = 'Book successfully modified!'
  end
end
```

The problem with my approach is that sometimes the validation about the page_number that I have defined on Pages model is bypassed and I get an error directly from PG ("PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint").

This scenario happens on 2 cases:

1. Trying to create two or more pages with the same number directly **on one form submission**
2. Updating existing page_number (ex from page_number: 4 to nr: 5) and creating one new page with number 4 **on one form submission**.

It seems that there is some problem of concurrency and order of processing the updates/creates.

For the point 2, we should somehow tell Rails to look over all records and see if there we are trying to do any duplication by combining updates with creates. Point 2 is a valid option and there should be no validation error thrown but because Rails is doing creation first it laments that a page with page_number 4 already exists (without taking into considerance that page_number 4 is being updated to 5)

I would be thankful I you could advice me how to handle this situation and be able to predict all use cases so that I do not hit the database in case of a validation error.

If this is impossible, is there a way that I can catch the error from Postgres, format and display it to the user?

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: Race conditions with application level uniqueness validations is a very old and known problem. Whats happening here is that you're sending two queries to the database to see if a page with that page_number exists and since neither of them have been inserted they both get an OK. `validates_uniqueness_of` only checks that the record doesn't exist in the database - not that an unsaved collection doesn't contain duplicates.

Comment: I would really recommend this article - https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations it explains how this happens a lot better then I can even if it doesn't really contain any solutions.

Comment: The exceptions from the database driver can be caught just like any other exception - with `rescue PG::UniqueViolation`.

Comment: @max thank you for your explanation. What do you suggest doing in this case, just rescuing from PG::UniqueViolation, or I should refactor my code logic? We have to consider also the scenario 2 that I took the example. It is a valid example and no validation error should be thrown.

Comment: Rescueing the data base dirver error seems like a pretty dire measure. I guess you could add a validation to Book where you check if any of the Page records in memory contain duplicate page numbers. Which handles part of the problem. Not completely sure how to handle when updating "frees up a slot".